# Sinkhole noisy application in journald

Tags: systemd

I've got an app that puts a lot of "noise" (really unnecessary logs) into my syslog. Can I setup journald somehow that it sends all of those logs to /dev/null instead of journal?

Answer (score 1):

## How do I sinkhole a noisy application from the system log?

**tl;dr**: Use `rsyslog` and discard (`~`) matching log lines

---

From reading the [journald.conf manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/journald.conf.5.html), it doesn't seem to be possible to do application-level filtering via `journald` itself.

However, you could forward all to `rsyslog`*, which has a [discard action](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html#discard):

> Discard can be highly effective **if you want to filter out some annoying messages** that otherwise would fill your log files. To do that, place the discard actions early in your log files. This often plays well with property-based filters, giving you great freedom in specifying what you do not want.
>
> Discard is just the single tilde character with no further parameters:
>
> `~`

*Note that `journald` may already be forwarding to `(r)syslog`; the default for me in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` certainly reflected that:

```
 #ForwardToSyslog=yes
```